# htaccess rewrite url parameter with defined values

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite URLs like this

```
www.url.com?host_interface=220?222?770
```

Into this (this the the one the user should see)

```
www.url.com/host_interface-usb,firewire,pcie.html
```

For this example I need to replace these parameters:

```
220 = usb
222 = firewire
770 = pcie
```

To make the url above better readable I exchanged the "%2C" to "?"

```
? = %2C
```

So, it actually looks like this

```
220%2C222%2C770
```

Do I need to translate this too?

besides the parameter the

```
?host_interface=
```

need to rewriten to

```
host_interface-
```

also its needs the ending

```
.html
```

So at the end I want to place several parameter like

xyz = abx

in the htaccess so all the parameters gets to be rewritten.

Comment: So, which version is the user going to see, and which version actually goes to the script? The user goes to `host_interface-usb,firewire,pcie.html` and behind the scenes gets redirected to `index.php?host_interface=220?222?770`?

Comment: Complete and concrete examples speak by themselves. I suggest you place at least one  in your question. i.e. This is the requested URL, this the URL to show and this is the address of the resource; this variable nn/XXX becomes nn/XXX in the resource-address or in the URL-to-show; this parameter is removed or modified to... etc.

Comment: i changed that i thought this was clear readable, sorry!

Comment: i have this url www.url.com?host_interface=220%2C222%2C770 now and need to translate it into this www.url.com/host_interface-usb,firewire,pcie.html